# How do i use OnKeypress to use my button depending the key pressed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onkeypress, howler.js

Hi i want to reproduce a sound depending on the key pressed but how do i passed into my onkeypress?
i reproduce the sound with howler and the i used a map function to reproduce and create a button for all the buttons but i dont know how to use it with a onkeypress, like i want it to change the button sound if i press another key like w,etc

```
//create an array for audioClips
const audioClips = [
{sound : bass, label: "BassDrum"},
{sound : hithat, label: "HitHat"},
{sound : ride, label: "Ride"},
{sound : snare, label: "Snare"},
{sound : splash, label: "Splash"},
{sound : tom, label: "Tom"},
]
class App extends Component {
SoundPlay = (src) => {
const sound = new Howl({
  src
});
sound.play();
}

RenderButtonAndSound = () => {
  return audioClips.map((soundObj,index) => {
    return(
      <button key={index}onKeyPress={() => this.SoundPlay(soundObj.sound)} onClick={() => 
 this.SoundPlay(soundObj.sound) }>
        {soundObj.label}
      </button>
    )
  });
  
 }

 render(){
Howler.volume(1.0)
return (
  <div className="App">
    <h2>
      My Virtual Drums
    </h2>
    {this.RenderButtonAndSound()}
  </div>
 );
 }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the onKeyPress event, you can check the keys being entered.

```
   const keyboardEvents = (event) =>{
       console.log(event.key); // this will return string of key name like 'Enter'
       console.log(event.keyCode) //using keycode

  if (e.keyCode == 13) { //Press Enter
    this.SoundPlay(soundObj.sound)
  }

       //You can use If-Else or Switch statements to call different sound base on event.key
   }


RenderButtonAndSound = () => {
  return audioClips.map((soundObj,index) => {
    return(
      <button key={index} onKeyPress={(e) => this.keyboardEvents(e)} onClick={() => 
 this.SoundPlay(soundObj.sound) }>
        {soundObj.label}
      </button>
    )
  });
  
 }
```

Comment: when i compile it appear this src\App.js
  Line 40:57:  'e' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: thanks for the help but i m having problems implemmenting it, can you make a example with a random letter and sound

Comment: added a if-else statement to check for "Enter" key. when u press enter, it plays sound.